# Apache Cassandra visual interface

Tags: interface, cassandra

I installed Cassandra through the commandline and when I run `csqlsh`
 this is what I see in the command line: `Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.`

But there is nothing about open localhost on ... port or neither in the dowloaded file there is no local application, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Not sure at all what the actual question is here.  Voted to close.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see? Cassandra is a distributed database and doesn't have a visual interface.

Comment: Are you asking if Cassandra has a web interface?

Answer (score 1):

CQLSH is your Cassandra interface. Here is [reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlReferenceTOC.html) to the documentation. And [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCommandsTOC.html) is the reference to the cql commands.

Some [visual tools](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/index.html) you will get if you're using DSE.